# Error when sending to kafka : This record has failed the validation on broker and hence be rejected

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a java process publishing to kafka (hosted in confluent). When we dont process anything for few hours and then we re-try, we get the below error for all the messages. But after we restart, its all good and all of them process fine.

I tried the internet, but i could figure out how to proceed with this one. Next step might be to check the broker log? (which i dont have access to at my work). Is there something I can do from my client side to debug further?

```
2023-06-02 17:02:20,632 pid:[id] ERROR kafka.SimpleProducer  - java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.InvalidRecordException: This record has failed the validation on broker and hence be rejected.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.valueOrError(FutureRecordMetadata.java:98)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:67)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:30)
```

I managed to get the broker logs

```
{"exception":{"stacktrace":"org.apache.kafka.common.InvalidRecordException: One or more records have been rejected due to 1 record errors in total, and only showing the first three errors at most: [RecordError(batchIndex=0, message='Log record DefaultRecord(offset=0, timestamp=1685667829424, key=19 bytes, value=2083 bytes) is rejected by the record interceptor io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.validator.RecordSchemaValidator')]","exception_class":"org.apache.kafka.common.InvalidRecordException","exception_message":"One or more records have been rejected due to 1 record errors in total, and only showing the first three errors at most: [RecordError(batchIndex=0, message='Log record DefaultRecord(offset=0, timestamp=1685667829424, key=19 bytes, value=2083 bytes) is rejected by the record interceptor io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.validator.RecordSchemaValidator')]"},"source_host":"xyz20092123456.obm.xxx.yyy.domain.com","method":"error","level":"ERROR","message":"[ReplicaManager broker=1] Error processing append operation on partition my-service-request-dev-xxx-2","mdc":{"brokerId":"1"},"@timestamp":"2023-06-02T01:03:49.490Z","file":"Logging.scala","line_number":"76","thread_name":"data-plane-kafka-request-handler-7","@version":1,"logger_name":"kafka.server.ReplicaManager","class":"kafka.utils.Logging"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The broker can reject messages due to being too large, bad authentication, quotas being exceeded, schema protection, etc.

The broker logs might provide more details, but based on having it work after waiting, I'd guess it's quota limits, which are enabled by default in Confluent Cloud.

Comment: Only when the java process publishing (Simple Producer), is kept running for few hours this is an issue. If i run another process it works just fine. Also if i restart daemon process and re-run it works too. Not sure if it has something to do with the connection needing a refresh. Added the broker logs.

Comment: As mentioned, the broker has schema protection enabled - `RecordSchemaValidator`, and so your producer is using an incorrect schema, it seems. Check your schema registry

Comment: But when i rerun the process it works fine with the same everything. Only thing i do is reconnect and re publish from the same consumer (and exact same record)

Comment: Is it possible that someone else / other process is also producing data to that topic, and may be auto registering their schemas, causing yours to be overridden until you restart? As suggested, check your schema registry for how many versions are used on that topic/subject

Comment: That could exactly be the reason. I am at my work, where kafka is hosted via confluent platform. How can get the registered schema on that topic? There is a devops team who i can ask to. But is there a command line or something i can check? Saw this -> https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#compatibility but not sure how i can run this.

Comment: Confluent Cloud has an API, yes, but you can also login to its UI, if you have access to either. That would be the only way

Comment: I can see the schema registry now. It has 2 version (It looks like the latest and the one before). I can also see in my client there is auto.register.schemas = true, which i think explains why it starts working after a restart. Next part I think is that I have to figure out which schema was used by the topic at a given point in time.

Comment: Also i can see that producer is using topic subject name strategy. So its going to be versioned schemas i guess. So my understanding is V1 is the schema deployed as baseline and V2 is the auto registered schema by the producer, which is the latest. At some point, the broker switches the schema and going forward all messages breaks. Simple solution is to re-register the schema (which is what is happening when we restart the service)

Comment: That's the default strategy, yes. The broker doesn't maintain or modify schema information, only your clients and the registry do. If you try to re-register v1 schema after any v2 schema, that's a non backwards compatible change. You can disable backward compatibility checks for the subject, if you wish

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to auto registering schemas by the publisher (which gets deleted due to retention policy, which is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76461321/when-does-schema-registry-remove-the-schemas-which-are-auto-registered/76468120#76468120))

Solution is to turn off auto registration of schemas and use the latest version always

```
auto.register.schemas=false
use.latest.version=true
```