# When does schema registry remove the schemas which are auto registered

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I have situation in my development environment where my client has auto.register.schemas = true. This works fine for a while, but at some point the schema registry removes it ( i am using kafka hosted in confluent) and all my messages fails which are after that. I tracked it down to when the schema registry gets rid of my auto registered schema.

When do schema registry remove the auto registered schema by a client producer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with any Kafka topic, it should never do that unless the schemas topic was created with `cleanup.policy=delete` (or `compact,delete`). The topic should have compact policy, therefore keep data forever.

Comment: It has cleanup.policy=delete. So does that mean it will delete all the auto registered schemas along with the messages for the delete.retention.ms (wchich is set to 24hrs in my case)? I noticed that there is one version left always (which i assume is called "base schema").

Comment: Yes. The documentation explicitly says the topic should be compact